# Spring Boot PersistentBag remove() throws UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

According to [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations) i implemented the following parent-child bidirectional entity association

```
public class Parent { 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = parent, cascade = CasacadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true) 
    private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();

    public void removeChild(Child child) {
        children.remove(child);
        child.setParent(null);
    }
}

public class Child {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private Parent parent;
}
```

Now even if i do a **remove()** operation, a *UnsupportedOperationException* is thrown,
because Spring always return a **PersistentBag** which is **not supporting** remove(), removeAll() or clear()

How can i remove a child from the parent?

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods if you intend to use reattachment of detached instances.
Hibernate guarantees equivalence of persistent identity (database row) and Java identity only inside a particular session scope. So as soon as we mix instances retrieved in different sessions, we must implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`.([Ref](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/4.3/html/hibernate_reference_guide/persistent_classes-implementing_equals_and_hashcode))

Note: In given article `equals()` and `hashCode()` are also implemented.

For eager fetching `remove()` will not work([Ref](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3799)).
Use the `FetchType.LAZY` strategy for `@ManyToOne` associations because by default `@ManyToOne` associations use the `FetchType.EAGER`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But equals() and hashCode() are already implemented/overridden.

Comment: @Eldon implemented in your class ? and child are lazily loaded right ?

Comment: Yes you are right. Implemented in my class and i load it lazy

Comment: You don't use @ManyToOne as FetchType.LAZY right and why you are not postinging your full implementation here ?